# ModalBottomSheetLayout not opening again in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

I was learning `ModalBottomSheetLayout` in my project. I have a `Button` and `onClick` I am sending `Boolean` to show `sheetContent`. It works once without any problem. After clicking on outside of `ModalBottomSheetLayout` it closes the `sheetContent`. After again clicking on `Button, sheet is not opening again. I don't understand what is the problem in here.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding by lazy { ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainActivityViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        viewModel.enableBottomSheet.observe(this) {
            binding.bottomSheetComposeView.setContent {
                ModalBottomSheetSample(it)
            }
        }

        binding.buttonComposeView.setContent {
            ButtonView()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun ButtonView() {
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Button(onClick = {
                viewModel.enableBottomSheet.postValue(true)
            }) {
                Text(text = "Open Bottom Sheet")
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    fun ModalBottomSheetSample(value: Boolean) {
        val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden, skipHalfExpanded = true)
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        SideEffect {
            scope.launch {
                if (value) {
                    state.show()
                }
            }
        }
        ModalBottomSheetLayout(
            sheetState = state,
            sheetContent = {
                LazyColumn {
                    items(5) {
                        ListItem(
                            icon = {
                                Icon(
                                    Icons.Default.Favorite,
                                    contentDescription = null
                                )
                            },
                            text = { Text("Item $it") },
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        ) {}
    }

}
```

**MainActivityViewModel.kt**

```
class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val enableBottomSheet by lazy { MutableLiveData(false) }
}
```

**Output**

Here in this [video](https://youtube.com/shorts/YiHVqOuLMu0?feature=share), you can clearly see 1st time open the Bottom sheet on Button click. But not open for next click. Thanks

I am using `compose_bom = "2023.03.00"`. Please don't suggested alpha or beta fix.

Comment: I see in your code only .show() to show the bottomSheet, and you don’t call .hide() at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changes two things.

1. Change State of function i.e. `StateFul` and `StateLess` separate function.
2. Change from `LiveData` to `MutableSharedFlow` and it working fine.

**MainActivityViewModel.kt**

```
class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val showBottomSheetContent by lazy { MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>() }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HideViewListener {

    private val binding by lazy { ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainActivityViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.showBottomSheetContent
                    .collect { value ->
                        binding.bottomSheetComposeView.setContent {
                            ModalBottomSheetSample(value)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

        binding.buttonComposeView.setContent {
            ButtonViewContent()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun ButtonViewContent() {
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        viewModel.showBottomSheetContent.emit(true)
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = "Open Bottom Sheet")
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    fun ModalBottomSheetSample(value: Boolean) {
        val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden, skipHalfExpanded = true)
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        SideEffect {
            scope.launch {
                if (value) {
                    sheetState.show()
                }
            }
        }
        ModalBottomSheetContent(sheetState)
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun ModalBottomSheetContent(sheetState: ModalBottomSheetState) {
        ModalBottomSheetLayout(
            sheetState = sheetState,
            sheetContent = {
                LazyColumn {
                    items(5) {
                        ListItem(
                            icon = {
                                Icon(
                                    Icons.Default.Favorite,
                                    contentDescription = null
                                )
                            },
                            text = { Text("Item $it") },
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        ) {}
    }

}
```